# How to get `self` in http Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Firebase authentication in a Python HTTP Google Cloud function.
But the function `verify_id_token()` requires `self` as an argument. How do I get `self` in an HTTP Google Cloud Function? This is my current method:

```
def main(request):
    print(self)
    # Handle CORS
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return '', 204, headers
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
    # Validate Firebase session
    if 'authorization' not in request.headers:
        return f'Unauthorized', 401, headers
    authorization = str(request.headers['authorization'])
    if not authorization.startswith('Bearer '):
        return f'Unauthorized', 401, headers
    print(authorization)
    id_token = authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]
    print(id_token)
    decoded_token = auths.verify_id_token(id_token)
    uid = str(decoded_token['uid'])
    if uid is None or len(uid) == 0:
        return f'Unauthorized', 401, headers
```

I already tried adding `self` as a parameter to the `main` function, but that does not work since `request` has to be the first parameter and no second parameter is set, so neither `def main(self, request)` nor `def main(request, self)` work.

Comment: "But the function verify_id_token() requires self as an argument." I assume you know this because you read the documentation? Then the problem appears to be that you do not *understand* the documentation, because you are not familiar with common Python conventions. This is best addressed by following a tutorial and learning the fundamentals first; but if you include a link to the documentation in question then it might be possible to explain what you are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**main** is a method and not a class. Methods that are not members of a class do not have **self**.

Comment: Oh. That makes. I guess wrapping the method in a class would fix the issue?

Comment: @radmacher - why do you think you need **self** at all. Your code does not need it.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I completely messed up. The problem was, that I did not initialize the Firebase Admin SDK correctly. You were right, I never needed `self`. Thank you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is a reference to object itself. Let's say you have a class with properties (methods, attributes). If you want to access to any one of properties inside the class itself, you'll need `self` (some languages call it `this`. Such as JavaScript).

If you create an object from that class and want to access to any one of properties you would use the object name.

Example:

```
class MyClass:

   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def method1(self):
      print("Method 1 is called")

   def method2(self):
      print("I'll call method 1")
      self.method1()
```

See, if one wants to call `method2` from `method1` they will need `self`.

But if you create an object from `MyClass` you can access any property using the variable name:

```
mc = MyClass()
mc.method1()
```

### TL;DR

You can't (and you do NOT need to) access `self` outside the scope of a class.